Taking Challah: Practical Question
All accounts I read about taking Challah refer to pounds or kilos of flour used.
Here’s my question:  How do these amounts translate into actual loaves of bread?  (As a non-baker, those kilos etc don’t mean anything to me.)
If I bake one loaf of challah (the size of an average store-bought challah), is that enough to take Challah?  If not, two loaves?
Can someone put this in loaf terms?
Thank you!!

"Loaf" is not a well defined unit, especially since dough can rise a lot or a little depending on a myriad of factors

It's impossible to know ,since every loaf is shaped differently  and weighs a different amount . It goes based off the flour amount,just for example ,if you baked a small challah only chances are you aren't required, but of you made a very large challah for a wedding than certainly it would be the required amount, that is why loaf amount isn't a good measuring example

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

The New York Times Challah recipe uses 8 cups of flour and makes two loaves.
1 lb of all-purpose flour has a typical volume of 3.66 cups, ergo the Times recipe calls for ~2.2 lbs = ~ 1kg of flour.
The Star-K notes that there is definitely no obligation to take off challah from a dough less than 2.6 lbs of flour, or approximately 8.67 cups.
The New York Times recipe yields two decent-sized challahs, and is below the threshold.

8 cups and 8.67 cups is pretty close. Settling may account for the difference. Note you used 1lb:3.66cups but the StarK is assuming 2.6lbs:8.67==1lbs:3.33cups

@mbloch I assume she is taking challah with a blessing, which requires nearly 5lb of flour, not 2.6. For 2.6lb of flour, you'd take challah without making a blessing.

@Esther yes you are right of course
